# regex split based on exact character except when escaped with a backslash before it

Tags: java, regex, string, split, delimiter

Need to split a string using delimiter, but only if there is no backslash before the delimiter.

ex: if there is `abc \:abc` - do not split it as `:` has backslash before it.

if the string is `abc : abc` - need to split as `abc, abc`.

The delimiters can be `:,|,&` etc.

Comment: Do you want to be able to escape the backslash, e.g. `abc \\: def` to split into ``abc \`` and `def`?

Comment: Hi, its an interesting testcase. yes \\ should be together and : should be used to split in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative look-behind `(?<!...)`. To match a literal backslash `\`, you have to escape twice. Once to escape because it's a string literal, and again because it's a regex escape character.

```
String[] parts = string.split("(?<!\\\\)[:,|&]");
```

Comment: Another nice point to comment is that lookarounds _assert_ but do not consume.  This is the behavior wanted, to consume the actual delimiter while leaving the non slash character intact.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lookbehind as the split expression:

```
String input = "abc \\:abc def : def";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=[^\\\\]):");
                                    ^^^^ split on any non-slash
                                         followed by delimiter
```

[**IDEOne**](http://ideone.com/UoRMjq)

Comment: @4castle I tested your negative lookbehind and it also seems to be working.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks, and no problem. Just a note for the OP, the only difference between our answers is how the regex handles a delimiter at the start of the string. For example, if the string was `:abc`, yours wouldn't split, and mine would. It may be though that this corner case would never happen.

Comment: You should use `(?<!\\\\)` because it's simpler, but also because it caters for the first char being a separator. If you use a positive look behind, there has to actually be a character there (which I just noticed 4castle has already posted...)

Comment: @Bohemian Playing the devil's advocate, if the string _ended_ in `word:`, then wouldn't the final match have a delimiter in it using your method?

Comment: @tim both would match and split on the trailing delimiter, but java's split discards empty trailing elements (unless you invoke the overloaded version with a large or negative `limit`). The difference is only at the start, because `^` doesn't match a PLB for a character